# Unable to display a RecyclerView with Retrofit in first fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit2

I started using Retrofit instead of Volley for the sake of speed and easy of implementation.

For some context I'm using a BottomNavigationBar with Fragments and I can't display first in my application (after the splash screen) the Fragment which loads the data with Retrofit. If I display another Fragment and I search for my Fragment in question everything works fine.

My code for load data in fragment

```
binding.recyclerViewUser.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
binding.recyclerViewUser.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(mContext, usersList, 4);
binding.recyclerViewUser.setAdapter(usersAdapter);

Call<List<UsersModel>> getUersData = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getUsersData();
getUersData.enqueue(new Callback<>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<UsersModel>> call, @NonNull Response<List<UsersModel>> response) {
    usersList = response.body();
    usersAdapter.setUsersList(usersList);

    Log.d("Retrofit success", "Yeah!");

    long requestTime = response.raw().sentRequestAtMillis();
    long responseTime = response.raw().receivedResponseAtMillis();
    long apiTime =  responseTime - requestTime;

    Log.d("Retrofit time", apiTime + "ms");
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<UsersModel>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
    Log.d("Retrofit error", t.getMessage());
  }
});
```

Now my error when I want to load my Fragment first in my application

```
2022-08-09 10:03:18.944 7422-7422/com.package.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.package.app, PID: 7422
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.package.app.adapter.UsersAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UsersAdapter.java:49)
        at com.package.app.adapter.UsersAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UsersAdapter.java:23)
```

The error of corresponds to nothing, first `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` is already defined in this line `usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(mContext, usersList, 4);` **the int of 4 returns the size**

And the other error `at com.package.app.adapter.UsersAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UsersAdapter.java:49)` matches this line `holder.name.setText(usersList.get(position).getName());` but I can load my RecyclerView when it's not showing in first position in my application.

I show you my UsersAdapter, maybe I missed a few things but everything seems correct to me

```
public class UsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.UsersHolder> {
  Context mContext;
  List<UsersModel> usersModel;
  int size;

  public UsersAdapter(Context mContext, List<UsersModel> usersModel, int size) {
      this.mContext = mContext;
      this.usersModel = usersModel;
      this.size = size;
  }

  public void setUsersList(List<UsersModel> usersModel) {
      this.usersModel = usersModel;
      notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  @NonNull
  @Override
  public UsersAdapter.UsersHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_users, parent, false);
      return new UsersHolder(view);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersAdapter.UsersHolder holder, int position) {
      holder.name.setText(usersModel.get(position).getName());
      holder.description.setText(usersModel.get(position).getDescription());
      Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext().getApplicationContext()).load(usersModel.get(position).getLogo()).into(holder.logo);
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
      return size;
  }

  public static class UsersHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      private final ImageView logo;
      private final TextView name, description;

      public UsersHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
          super(itemView);
          logo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
          name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
          description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
      }
  }
}
```

If anyone can help me I would be very grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Adapter created when your list is empty, you can change your code like this:

```
binding.recyclerViewUser.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
binding.recyclerViewUser.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);

Call<List<UsersModel>> getUersData = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getUsersData();
getUersData.enqueue(new Callback<>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<UsersModel>> call, @NonNull Response<List<UsersModel>> response) {
    usersList = response.body();
    usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(mContext, usersList, 4);
    binding.recyclerViewUser.setAdapter(usersAdapter);
    usersAdapter.setUsersList(usersList);

    Log.d("Retrofit success", "Yeah!");

    long requestTime = response.raw().sentRequestAtMillis();
    long responseTime = response.raw().receivedResponseAtMillis();
    long apiTime =  responseTime - requestTime;

    Log.d("Retrofit time", apiTime + "ms");
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<UsersModel>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
    Log.d("Retrofit error", t.getMessage());
  }
});
```

Suggest:
you don't need put your list in constructor of Adapter, *setUserList* method did it for you

Answer (score 0):

you can try to create adapter and assign list after filling the list. You can try the following code;

```
binding.recyclerViewUser.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
binding.recyclerViewUser.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);


Call<List<UsersModel>> getUersData = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getUsersData();
getUersData.enqueue(new Callback<>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<UsersModel>> call, @NonNull
            Response<List<UsersModel>> response) {
        usersList = response.body();
        usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(mContext, usersList, 4);
        binding.recyclerViewUser.setAdapter(usersAdapter);

        Log.d("Retrofit success", "Yeah!");

        long requestTime = response.raw().sentRequestAtMillis();
        long responseTime = response.raw().receivedResponseAtMillis();
        long apiTime =  responseTime - requestTime;

        Log.d("Retrofit time", apiTime + "ms");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<UsersModel>> call, @NonNull Throwable t){
        Log.d("Retrofit error", t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Override
  public int getItemCount() {
      return usersModel.size();
  }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, 
**[including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) 
really helps to improve the quality of your post**. Remember that you are 
answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might 
not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd 
your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both 
the code and the explanations!